# emacs flyspell disable for custom latex macros

Tags: regex, emacs, latex, elisp, flyspell

I have the following LaTeX code which has some custom macro's and environments which i would like to exclude from flyspell.

```
Some normal text

\begin{customenv}
Please dont flyspell-this
\end{customenv}

again some normal text (please flyspell this) and some \customcode{dont-flyspell-this}.
```

I know I need to write a function to pass to flyspell-mode-predicate but I'm haveing some trouble getting it to work for both the \customcode and the \begin{customenv} and \end{customenv}.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update:**
It seems i can set the following:

```
(setq flyspell-tex-command-regexp
"\\(\\((\\(begin\\|end\\)[ \t]*{\\|\\(cite[a-z*]*\\|label\\|ref\\|eqref\\|usepackage\\|documentclass\\|customcode\\)[ \t]*\\(\\[[^]]*\\]\\)?{[^{}]*\\)\\|\\\\begin{\\(customenv[1-9]*\\)}\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\\\end{\\(customenv[1-9]*\\)}\\)")
```

This seems to work for the `\customcode{stuff}` but it still doesn't skip the text in `customenv`

Comment: The answer will probably look something like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer/345461#345461).

Comment: indeed, however i can't seem to create a function that will work for both the custom macro and the custom enviroment at the same time.

Comment: Could you write separate functions for the macro and the environment?  If so, you can chain both easily.